# Docker nginx reverse proxy can't resolve hostname

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nextcloud

I'm trying to setup nextcloud with a nginx reverse proxy in front of it. Therefore I'm using docker compose, with one service each. All containers are in the same network (nextcloud-aio).
If I attach to the nginx container, install ping and ping the hostname `nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer` everything works just fine. But if I access the webserver, it logs `no resolver defined to resolve nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer`.
I just mounted the working nginx configuration to the docker-container and changed the hostname for the proxy_pass from 127.0.0.1 to nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer. the proxy_pass inside the container is now `proxy_pass http://nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer:11000$request_uri;`
I've read about wrong reolv.conf files, but I guess, the ping should fail also if thats the problem.
Just for the case somebody asks, this is my /etc/resolv.conf inside the container:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Hopefully somebody has an idea I could try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;` to the nginx.conf and replaced `nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer` with `nextcloud-aio-apache`. It works like a charm now